# Copy subfolder with groovy in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cloudbees

I am trying to script a groovy script which copies a complete folder with all subfolder and jobs to the actual folder, where the script is executed.

Here you can see how my folderstructure looks like.

```
--> Templ
      |-->Folder
      |-->Folder
           |-->Subfolder
                   |-->Subsubfolder
           |-->Subfolder
      |-->Folder
-->Execution 2020
      |-->Copyscript
```

I tried with different Plug-Ins like Jobcopy Builder.
Finally I tried with groovy scrips but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try to use File Operations plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-operations ?

Comment: Yes, but when you move files with this plugin you have to restart your Jenkins because it moves the files directly on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to use AntBuilder

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.copy(todir: myDir) {
    fileset(dir: "src/test") {
        include(name: "**/*.java")
    }
}
```

example taken from here

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/ant-builder.html

to see all parameters of ant copy command see documentation:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html